# Are sentences from the same document independent and identically distributed?

Tags: machine-learning, datasets, long-short-term-memory, cross-entropy

I am trying to build an LSTM model to generate Shakspeare-like poems. I have data set $\{s_1, s_2, \dots, s_m \}$, which are sentences of Shakespeare poems, and each sentence contains words $\{w_1, w_2, \dots, w_n \}$.

I am wondering:  Are different $s_i$ ($i=1, \dots, m$) independent and identically distributed samples (IID)? Are $w_i$ ($i=1, \dots, n$) within each sentence the IID?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The sentences coming from the same document, author, etc., are unlikely to be [independent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Independence_(probability_theory)), that is, the occurrence of a sentence $s_i$ in a certain document $d$ is likely correlated with the occurrence of another sentence $s_j$. If they are not independent, they can also not be independent and identically distributed (which is a stronger condition). The same can be said for words in the same sentence.